# Find nearest neighbors of a numpy array in list of numpy arrays using euclidian distance

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, nearest-neighbor

I have a n-dimensional vector and I want to find its k nearest neighbors in a list of n-dimensional vectors using euclidian distance.

I wrote the following code (with k=10) which works but runs too slowly and I was wondering if there was a more optimal solution.

```
def nearest_neighbors(value, array, nbr_neighbors=1):
    return np.argsort(np.array([np.linalg.norm(value-x) for x in array]))[:nbr_neighbors]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use scipy's [kd-tree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree).

A small example is [available here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query).

Many people seem to complain about the performance and recommend [sklearn's implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) though (links sklearn.neighbors, which is using this [data-structure](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.KDTree) internally)!

Comment: SciPy has [cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html]) which is significantly faster than the KDTree.

Comment: Updated link: [cKDtree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html)

Comment: Using cKDtree instead of [KDtree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) is no longer recommended by SciPy except for backwards compatibility, as they are now identical.  From the cKDtree documentation page linked above:

"Prior to SciPy v1.6.0, cKDTree had better performance and slightly different functionality but now the two names exist only for backward-compatibility reasons. If compatibility with SciPy < 1.6 is not a concern, prefer KDTree."

Answer (score 3):

As sascha said, I ended up using the scipy library (but the `NearestNeighbors` method) which brought down the computation time from 50 hours to 36 minutes. It is the kind of computation I should not have tried to reimplement myself as dedicated libraries are much more optimized for this.

The `NearestNeighbors` method also allows you to pass in a list of values and returns the k nearest neighbors for each value.

Final code was:

```
def nearest_neighbors(values, all_values, nbr_neighbors=10):
    nn = NearestNeighbors(nbr_neighbors, metric='cosine', algorithm='brute').fit(all_values)
    dists, idxs = nn.kneighbors(values)
```

Comment: You should select HIS answer as the answer and add this to your post as an end edit.

Comment: This only works for 2d data. higher dimensions won't work

Answer (score -2):

I would try using the pdist function of scipy to find the pairwise distances by brute force : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html

It should be quite fast as pdist is highly optimized. Then for each element pick the k nearest.