# Efficient way for Computing the Similarity of Multiple Documents using Spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, similarity, sentence-similarity

I have around 10k docs (mostly 1-2 sentences) and want for each of these docs find the ten most simliar docs of a collection of 60k docs. Therefore, I want to use the spacy library. Due to the large amount of docs this needs to be efficient, so my first idea was to compute both for each of the 60k docs as well as the 10k docs the document vector (https://spacy.io/api/doc#vector) and save them in two matrices. This two matrices can be multiplied to get the dot product, which can be interpreted as the similarity.
Now, I have basically two questions:

1. Is this actually the most efficient way or is there a clever trick that can speed up this process
2. If there is no other clever way, I was wondering whether there is at least a clever way to speed up the process of computing the matrices of document vectors. Currently I am using a for loop, which obviously is not exactly fast:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
doc_matrix = np.zeros((len(train_list), 300))
for i in range(len(train_list)):
  doc = nlp(train_list[i]) #the train list contains the single documents
  doc_matrix[i] = doc.vector
```

Is there for example a way to parallelize this?

Comment: maybe should search answer on similar portal for [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do a big matrix operation, instead put your document vectors in an approximate nearest neighbors store ([annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) is easy to use) and query the nearest items for each vector.

Doing a big matrix operation will do `n * n` comparisons, but using approximate nearest neighbors techniques will partition the space to perform many fewer calculations. That's much more important for the overall runtime than anything you do with spaCy.

That said, also check the [spaCy speed FAQ](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8402).

Answer (score 2):

I personally never worked with sentence similarity/vectors in SpaCy directly, so I can't tell you for sure about your first question, there might be some clever way to do this which is more native to SpaCy/the usual way to do it.

For generally speeding up the SpaCy processing:

1. [Disable components you don't need](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#disabling) such as Named Entity Recognition, Part of Speech Tagging etc.
2. Use `processed_docs = nlp.pipe(train_list)` instead of calling nlp inside the loop. Then access with `for doc in processed_docs:` or `doc = next(processed_docs)` inside the loop. You can tune the pipe() parameters to speed it up even more, depending on your hardware, see [the documentation](https://spacy.io/api/language#pipe).

For your actual "find the n most similar" problem:

This problem is not NLP- or SpaCy-specific but a general problem. There are a lot of sources on how to optimize this for numpy vectors online, you are basically looking for the n nearest datapoints within a large dataset (10000) of high dimensional (300) data. Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53455909/python-optimized-most-cosine-similar-vector) for some general ideas or [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742199/find-nearest-neighbors-of-a-numpy-array-in-list-of-numpy-arrays-using-euclidian) to for how to perform this kind of search (in this case K-nearest neighbours search) on numpy data.

Generally you should also not forget that in a large dataset (unless filtered) there are going to be documents/sentences which are duplicates or nearly duplicates (only differ by comma or so), so you might want to apply some filtering before performing the search.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try these hints :)