# spaCy: Which component of the pre-trained en_core_web_md pipeline contains the morphologizer/morphological analysis?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I need the mentioned pre-trained pipeline to analyze the morphological features of my text.

To disable the rest of the modules I don't need in my pipeline to make the analysis more resource-efficient I tried to find out in which components the morphological analysis for this pipeline is done.

The documentation is unclear. Does someone know this?

Answer (score 1):

All components enabled:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
print(nlp.pipe_names)
> ['tok2vec', 'tagger', 'parser', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer', 'ner']

doc = nlp("A man walks into a bar.")
print(doc[2].morph)
> Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin
```

If you disable `'tagger'` morph does not return anything and prints a warning:

```
\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\lemmatizer.py:211: UserWarning: [W108] The rule-based lemmatizer did not find POS annotation for one or more tokens. Check that your pipeline includes components that assign token.pos, typically 'tagger'+'attribute_ruler' or 'morphologizer'.
  warnings.warn(Warnings.W108)
```

Which is the main answer to your question, since the `_md` model does not have an explicit `morphologizer` component, disabling one of `tagger` or `attribute_ruler` means that morph doesnt work any more.

However what I found interesting is that disabling `tok2vec` will cause the morph info to be less detailed (no matter if disabled on loading the model or on handing a sentence to the model):

```
doc = nlp("A man walks into a bar.", disable=["tok2vec"])
print(doc[2].morph)
> Number=Sing
```

So to answer your question if you need the (full) morphological data you could disable anything except `tagger`, `attribute_ruler` and `tok2vec`:

```
doc = nlp("A man walks into a bar.", disable=['parser', 'lemmatizer', 'ner'])
print(doc[2].morph)
> Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin
```

Also a general tip if you are looking for efficiency in SpaCy - if you are not already doing it, make sure to use `nlp.pipe(sentence_list)` instead of `nlp(sentence)` to batch process your sentences, this gives you a noticable speedup for larger number of documents, check out [my answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71594386/18189622).